# Loop image over audio, as AvidDV codec with ffMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, avid

I have been trying to understand ffMPEG and outputting a file with the DNxHD codec.

I keep getting an error `[swscaler @ 0x7feec601a200] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`

Here is what I've been working with:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v dnxhd -b:v 120M -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 out.mov
```

But I was wondering if it was possible to make an AvidDV SD version of the output? 1024x576 or 720x576 at 25fps? I know you can make other codecs, but an Avid one would make for fast import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `deprecated pixel format used`

This is a warning, not an error, and you can ignore it.

## DNxHD

The FFmpeg DNxHD encoder only supports valid DNxHD profiles. `ffmpeg` will output the list if you attempt to output unsupported width x height, frame rate, bitrate, and/or pixel format. Or [view the list](https://askubuntu.com/a/907515/59378) at another answer.

## DV

FFmpeg can output DV, but I'm not quite sure why you would want to. This is an old format and there are better, modern, lossless alternative intermediate formats for editing such as UT video (`ffmpeg` can encode and decode that too). Like DNxHD it will only output certain DV profiles, but it can use the `-target` option to make it arguably easier to use:

```
ffmpeg -i input -target ntsc-dv output.dv
```

Comment: Understandable to the codec choice, but we are using SD footage and there is no need to import HD, as it is to be muxed to DVD. With the above, would this work: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -target pal-dv -c:v dnxhd -b:v 120M -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48000 out.mov` or would the mix between the DNxHD and DV be wrong?

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv No, that won't work. `-target` options are `vcd`, `svcd`, `dvd`, `dv`, or `dv50`  with optional prefixes `pal-`, `ntsc-`, or `film-`. To generalize, it's only useful for encoding to DV and DVD formats.

Comment: Understood. I may go for the `-target pal-dv50` or `-target dvd` as the output would be DVD anyway